# Manhwa where the female lead was executed and reincarnated as her younger self

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I read this manhwa a long time ago. It was about a girl whose sister was in love with the king/emperor and was chosen to be his wife but the king/emperor had a mistress. The sister and her entire family ended up getting executed for committing treason against the king/emperor and the mistress.

The girl gets reincarnated into her younger self before the sister got married to the king/emperor and decides to get revenge on the king/emperor and the mistress for her sister’s misery and her family’s execution. She gets chosen as the king/emperor’s wife instead of the sister. Long story short, she and the king/emperor fall in love with each other and the mistress ends up getting executed for committing treason against the empress.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE. When exactly did you read this? If you do remember any extra details please [edit] them in to the question, nothing is too insignificant

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead or the other major characters?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Could this be *[Lady to Queen](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/lady-to-queen)*?

[image: Cover image of Lady to Queen]

> My sister Neil, who became the Emperor's Queen after having dreamt of fairy tales and true loves, came back divorced and accused of high treason. Our family, the Rochesters, were mercilessly executed. But by some miracle, I came back in time to before she was selected as the Emperor's Queen candidate. If I become queen in your stead, you and our family need not suffer. This life of yours can have a happy ending, sister. I promise.

Found with a search for `manhua regression emperor mistress`, which led me to a recommendation of it [here](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-remarried-empress/recommendations).